# After upgrade to Sitecore 6.6, thumbnail image size parameters are inappropriately passed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

We have upgraded from Sitecore 6.5 to 6.6, and after the upgrade we have images throughout the site which are now showing up with ugly black boxes around them.

Changing the `Media.DefaultImageBackgroundColor` and `Media.UseLegacyResizing` options does nothing. I mention the former only as an extra hint that caching may be involved somehow. Changing the settings on image fields, restarting the app pool and website, etc. does nothing to solve this problem.

Has anyone found this problem when upgrading to Sitecore 6.6? Any idea as to the cause or fix?

Comment: are the boxes around the image a css border or are they part of the image?

Comment: Part of the image. Sitecore constructs resized versions of images on the fly; one way this can happen is if URL parameters are passed for the size. The parameters seem to be passed inappropriately after the upgrade, in links autogenerated by image fields, but also attempts to change that by resaving items after resetting the image parameters does nothing.

Comment: Are the images that are affected stored all in Rich-Text fields, Image fields, or both?

Comment: I've seen it only in Image fields so far.

Comment: Which Revision of 6.6 did you upgrade to?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel , 131211.

Comment: Just to cover the base-case, did you clear the cache via the .../sitecore/admin/cache.aspx page? Also, can you add an example of the rendered URL of one of the images to your post, please? :)

Comment: I cleared the cache, yes. The URLs look like this: http://[domain]/~/media/3E1154DF10D142D0BBD273003C333A51.jpg?h=182&w=116

Comment: Have you tried turning the `.ashx` extensions back on?

Comment: If you want to delete the media cache then you should delete all files in `/App_Data/MediaCache`, which will cause them to regenerate on next request. Simply clearing the cache will not cause these to be deleted.

Comment: I tried that, jammykam. The problem seems to lie in the fact that the files are generated with the wrong sizes due to including the width and length parameters in the query string.

Comment: Did you try changing the width/height properties to MaxHeight/MaxWidth instead like I suggested in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the box around the entire image, or just top/bottom or left/right? If the latter, then is the height/width dimensions you have provided in the same scale as the original image?

Is not either set `AllowStretch` to true (pass in `as=true`) or use `MaxHeight`/`MaxWidth` parameters instead (pass in `mh=182` and `mw=116`) which will scale the image appropriately if needed.

This is a bit old, but the parameters should be the same... [Sitecore Image Parameters](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/5%203%20Enhancements/Image%20Enhancements.aspx)

Comment: Hi. I think we were the victims of caching, and I'm marking this as the correct answer because it would've worked as well as just removing the parameters which were hard-coded in the control (which we did, but wasn't reflected for a while in output, despite having taken steps to dump the cache). Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Good to hear it was resolved. So I assume it a browser cache issue, as opposed to a Sitecore cache issue then?

Comment: I really don't think so, and multiple people all ruled that out. Perhaps we are all numbskulls, however. :D Thanks again. Now we're having a new issue.